# JMeter.bat error prohibiting access to JMeter

Tags: batch-file, jmeter

After installing apache-jmeter-2.11, go to the bin folder and double click on the jmeter.bat. The command window appears with the following error:

```
Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

JMeter closes after pressing any key. How do I move forward?

Answer (score 0):

What's happen if you comment the following line in the jmeter.bat ?

```
set DUMP=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

(put `rem` at the beginning of the line)

Comment: When I comment the line - set DUMP=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError - I receive the following: "The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Unrecognized VM option '+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . ."

Comment: @dcwilson042 You could try to install a newer version of Java and to recover the file `jmeter.bat` as it was at the beginning. Then, if it still doesn't work, continue to comment each option which are given by error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the jmeter.bat file. Comment this line in jmeter.bat.

```
set DUMP=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

#set DUMP=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```